# QT : The kit needs to define a CMake tool to parse this project

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator

How can I set up CMake in a proper way?

Versions:
QT - 8.0.1
CMake - 3.23.2
OS:Windows 10 64 bit
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Install a standalone CMake into "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe",
and use that instead of the CMake installed via QT works for me.

[image: QTCreator CMake]